# How to purge versions of items older than the nth version for each item

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I'd like to purge rows from the sample table below, so that the three newest versions of each report (by Name) remain in the table.

The ReportID is the unique identifier. The records in the sample are sorted in descending order by CreateDate for each Name.

Can this be done in a T-SQL query or do I need to set up a cursor and walk through the table somehow?

```
CREATE TABLE #Reports (
    [ReportID] int
    , [Name] varchar(50)
    , [CreateDate] datetime);

INSERT INTO #Reports (ReportID, [Name], CreateDate)
VALUES (3255, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-28 22:33:28.587'),
(3243, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-26 01:24:34.183'),
(3203, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-19 13:47:48.580'),
(3156, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-13 16:54:01.317'),
(3147, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-13 13:35:02.627'),
(3141, '2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-04 13:57:41.427'),
(3248, 'Audit Income Statement', '2017-12-26 22:53:50.067'),
(3246, 'Audit Income Statement', '2017-12-26 17:42:39.227'),
(3244, 'Audit Income Statement', '2017-12-26 17:25:18.477'),
(3099, 'Audit Income Statement', '2017-11-24 15:33:10.333'),
(3091, 'Audit Income Statement', '2017-11-24 14:59:16.283'),
(3252, 'FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-28 22:33:28.260'),
(3240, 'FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-26 01:24:33.837'),
(3200, 'FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-19 13:47:48.267'),
(3153, 'FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report', '2017-12-13 16:54:01.067');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the last 3 versions  **(Corrected to keep last 3)**

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By Name ORder by CreateDate desc ) from #Reports
)
Delete from cte 
 Where RN>3

Select * from #Reports
```

**Updated Table**

```
ReportID    Name                                    CreateDate
3255        2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report    2017-12-28 22:33:28.587
3243        2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report    2017-12-26 01:24:34.183
3203        2018 FTR RE Budget Acceptance Report    2017-12-19 13:47:48.580
3248        Audit Income Statement                  2017-12-26 22:53:50.067
3246        Audit Income Statement                  2017-12-26 17:42:39.227
3244        Audit Income Statement                  2017-12-26 17:25:18.477
3252        FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report         2017-12-28 22:33:28.260
3240        FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report         2017-12-26 01:24:33.837
3200        FTR ND Budget Acceptance Report         2017-12-19 13:47:48.267
```

Comment: Now **that** is a nice answer! I very much appreciate it. I have used CTEs a few times before but never the OVER clause. That is pretty slick. Thank you.

Comment: @serbach Happy it helped